# Are Geekbench scores related to software version?

Tags: benchmarking

I was looking at MacBook Pro and macbook models of 2016 and 2017 and I noticed that the same model in Geekbech scores has much lover scores that in Geekbench 4

I also noticed that some review compare Geekbench score for 2017 with previous video or review made with Geekbench 3, so I thought that score values was absolute not relative to the software version use to make the benchmark

I find this a bit odd since I guess nobody test again old PC models at each Geekbench software release

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The numbers are only relative to other machines tested on the same version.

My machine on v3 = 32,000
on v4 = 19,000